# Marketing cloud and salesforce custom link not showing up

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-link

We have created two **Custom links** on the **Contact** object to resuscribe and unsuscribe from emails from Marketing Cloud:

**Resuscribe custom link**
[image: Resuscribe custom link]

**Unsuscribe custom link**
[image: Unsuscribe custom link]

However, when adding it to the page layout, these links do not show up on the Contact layout. In fact, we added a google maps link to see whether it would show up and it did. Hence, the issue seems to be with these custom links that connect to Marketing Cloud.

**Here is the layout settings**:
[image: The layout]

**Here is the visualization**
[image: Contact layout visualization]

Comment: If those are the links that came with Marketing Cloud Connect, I believe they no longer work anymore - maybe that’s why they are not visible on the layout. I’d open a support case to double-check

Comment: @zuzannamj Thanks, we've already opened a case. Is there any alternative to do this?